UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT , Can not estimate gas Ether.js V5
I am trying to get the estimated gas for the approval of a token. I am getting the error can not estimate gas.Below is my code
            const estimatedGas = await provider.estimateGas({
                to: to,
                from: from,
                data: callData,
                gasPrice: (await provider.getFeeData()).gasPrice._hex,
                value: value ? value : '0x00'
            })


I do have a balance in my account to handle that i do have a check it is as below
if (amountInWei.gt(erc20Balance)) {
                this.exceptionService.sendBadRequestException(RESPONSE_MESSAGES.STAKING_AMOUNT_EXCEEDS);
            }

Why i am getting the error of can not estimate gas , I guess it might go away by manually passing in the gas limit to estimateGas function . But why pass a manual gas to estimate gas .?

why are you doing it that way?
You should probably do it more like this:
provider.estimateGas.getFeeData().then(g => applyGasBuffer(g) //...

this can be done but it won't work with the transactions which involves the calls to other smart contracts , let it be a swap token call or staking a token which requires multiple transactions under the hood.

whats the issue making a static call, you making a static call in a single tx, static wont update the state, if you're dependent on updated state then either mock multiple calls using a wrapper, or estimate the gas after the intial dependent call updates
